# Easy way to find a storyboard layout and its associated code implementation?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am new to iOS development and am trying to familiarize myself with a large codebase project.

Is there a quick way to pick a single layout from a storyboard and find its code implementation?

As I said the code base is very big, there must be an easy way to link a layout to code associated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the storyboard - select a vc - click on the red icon here to show implementation of that vc

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.